# Background thread in a subclass of Application or foreground service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I'm developing an application that collect data from an external device throught wifi connection. I use a thread to do the job and it stores data into a db.

Is it a good idea to put the thread in a custom Application class (managed as singleton)? Or is it better if I put it inside a foreground service?

Comment: what do you mean by foreground service.

Comment: Use a Service. A static thread within the Application is pretty similar but a service is intended to be used for such a task.

Comment: foreground service: call startForeground(0, notification); from the service

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is built for stuff like this. It won't block your UI thread and will do your networking and storage in the background.

Here's a tutorial if you need one:

https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Answer (score 1):

Use an IntentService. IntentService uses a separate background thread, so it won't block the UI thread. It persists even if all of your Activities are in the background. The problem with AsyncTask is that it terminates if the Activity terminates. With IntentService, your download will merrily run along until it's finished.

If you *really do know* Android threading and you feel comfortable, then you can do your own threads. I observe, though, that it's much easier to use IntentService. The only downside is that IntentService threads can't be interrupted, but I doubt most developers need that feature.

To communicate from the IntentService to other components in your app, use LocalBroadcastReceiver. To "communicate" to the UI, use a notification.

Comment: Interesting... I vote for your response but I don't know if its a solution yet. Thanks anyway.